# Travis CI Error: Chromium revision is not downloaded. Run "npm install" or "yarn install"

Tags: continuous-integration, jestjs, yaml, travis-ci, puppeteer

I have a test suite which works perfect on local setup, here is the library:
https://github.com/IbrahimTanyalcin/RafX

However I cannot get it to work on Travis CI, I keep getting:
"Chromium revision is not downloaded"

Here is my yml file:
https://github.com/IbrahimTanyalcin/RafX/blob/master/.travis.yml

```
language: node_js
dist: trusty
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      # This is required to run new chrome on old trusty
      - libnss3
notifications:
  email: false
cache:
  directories:
    - node_modules
sudo: required
node_js:
  - "12.13.0"
env:
  #global:
  #  - PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=0
# allow headful tests
before_install:
  # Enable user namespace cloning
  - "sysctl kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1"
  # Launch XVFB
  - "export DISPLAY=:99.0"
  # - export CHROME_PATH="$(pwd)/chrome-linux/chrome"
  - "sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start"
  # wait for xvfb to boot 
  - sleep 3 
  # start your web application and listen on `localhost`
  # - google-chrome-stable --headless --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-port=9222 http://localhost &
install:
  - npm install
  - npm install -g puppeteer --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
  # - yarn add --dev jest-puppeteer
  # - yarn add puppeteer
script:
  - npm run testCI
```

And here is the failing build
https://travis-ci.org/IbrahimTanyalcin/RafX

I commented out some of the options I tried, I pretty much checked everywhere including puppeteer and jest docs, and actually took their recommended yml file.

I also tried to apply suggestions in this thread, but of no avail: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/2173

Any idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone struggling with this, it seems I have found a work around, in your `before install`:

```
before_install:
  - node node_modules/puppeteer/install.js
```

If you add these lines, you are manually invoking node to install puppeteer, I do not know why `npm install` fails, but this seems to solve the issue.

Comment: This worked like charm on windows!!!!!